# Selenium object identification

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium webdriver to test my application & i am facing difficulties in identifiying button on the same. the code snippet is like :

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="return sign(this);" value="Login">
```

and its xpath is :

```
html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/center/form/center/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/center/input[1]
```

Which object property to use and how?

Comment: please format your question

Comment: please provide the language and more html (around the button).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use that XPath.

I would hazard a guess that you used some sort of tool, whether it's Firebug or IDE, to generate that XPath. **Stop that now!**

XPath is fine to use, and can be used here, just not relying on the tools to generate it for you! That XPath is destined for failure!

You will need to provide more HTML, specifically **around** that button.

However, you should just be able to use something as simple as:

```
//input[@value='Login']
```

Comment: so are you suggesting to creat a customized XPATH & then use it??

Comment: Would you please suggest me the ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the xpath, if that is really stable. I found that it is much easier to define id tags in the html elements and the use a `By.id` locator. Alternatively you can use [css selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html), depending on the "uniqueness" of your button something like this could work:

```
By.cssSelector("input[value='Login']")
```